# Does authenticated encryption add any protection to a signed digital envelope?

Tags: public-key, signature, authenticated-encryption

The general scenario of hybrid encryption is to use public key cryptography for the exchange of a one time *session key* that can be used for the encryption of the plaintext with a symmetric encryption algorithm. A digital signature attached to that structure is what I know as a *digital envelope*. Furthermore, some resources agree that *sign-encrypt-sign* can help to prevent certain unlikely but possible attacks.

On the other hand, for strictly symmetric scenarios, the use of authenticated encryption is usually recommended as a default good practice.

Does it make sense to bring these two approaches together? Especially, would authenticated encryption (as opposed to *semantically secure but unauthenticated encryption*) provide any protection against any scenario not covered already by the digital signature?

Comment: Is "that structure" just the PK-encrypted-symmetric-key, or that together with $\hspace{1.78 in}$ the symmetrically encrypted plaintext? $\;$

Comment: Being SK the session key, M the message, SE(K, M) the symmetric encryption of M with the key K, and AE(K, M) the asymmetric encryption of M with the key K, "that structure" would be C=AE(recipient public key, SK) || SE(SK, M). The final scheme would have the form C2=AE(recipient public key, SK)||SE(SK, M||sign(M))||sign(SE(SK, M||sign(M)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you look at Signcryption; a short survey appears [here](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~dodis/ps/signcrypt-survey.pdf), and efficient schemes appear [here](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~dodis/ps/psep.pdf). Just signing then encrypting or vice versa in a naive way is not secure (especially in the multi-user setting). So you have to do this right. Once you have a concrete scheme, you then have to see what level of security the encryption scheme needs to be. Typically it does need to be CCA secure, and the way to build CCA-secure symmetric encryption is the same as authenticated encryption. (Note that doing hybrid encryption or KEM/DEM, you need both the asymmetric and symmetric parts to be CCA secure.)  However, it really depends on exactly what you are doing. Look at the cited references as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you! I stumbled upon *signcryption* a few days ago, but I ignored it since all the documentation I found pointed to a single author back in the 90's. These references give me a more promising starting point, but I guess my overall concern remains: has *signcryption* been sufficiently studied? Is it used as the building block on any protocol or algorithm? Are there effective advantages over the *sign-encrypt-sign* scheme?

Comment: There are two different things that people have done with signcryption. One is to come up with scheme that are more efficient than separately encrypting and signing; personally I don't find them very interesting. The other is to develop rigorous definitions and show how to do it right. This is non-trivial, especially in the (realistic) multiuser setting. It's actually very easy to do right once you know how, but it's important to know that otherwise bad things can happen. I don't know if sign-encrypt-sign meets the proper definitions; you can check that :-).

Answer (score 1):

If by authenticated encryption we mean encrypt-then-MAC then that provides some mitigation against side channel attacks - timing, error responses etc - because it allows you to detect that the message has been tampered before you start decrypting it and in something hopefully close to constant time.

It is perhaps worth mentioning that in TLS the opposite structure to yours is used and the signature is on the outside of the "envelope". Asymmetric key signing is used to authenticate the channel (i.e. that you are talking to whom you think you are). Then MAC is used to authenticate the integrity of the messages that are sent via that channel.

Comment: There seems to be an agreement about *sign-then-encrypt-then-sign* being a good practice. In that scenario, wouldn't the validation of the external signature (the one calculated over the encrypted message) be as efficient and time uniform as verifying the MAC in the encrypt-then-MAC setup?

Comment: You'll get the same guarantee of integrity but there is a difference in privacy - the external signature is in plain text whereas the MAC requires knowledge of the shared secret to use and doesn't expose any information about the sender anyway. Even in the situation where you don't care about exposing the signature, signature verification is usually a more expensive operation than MAC verification.

Comment: But if the external signature is computed over the encrypted content, what kind of information would it be leaking? About signature, it would need to be verified in any case, at least to verify the sender's identity. Having already verified the signature, would I win anything by verifying, in addition, a MAC?

Comment: You leak the sender's identity. This may or may not be a problem depending on the use case. As I understand it, the main rationale for the external signature in sign-encrypt-sign is to prevent a replay attack - i.e. to prove that the recipient of the message is the intended recipient. This relies on the difficulty of reproducing the same shared secret as was used to encrypt when sending to the original, intended recipient. There are other ways to achieve this.

Comment: My impression of the reason for sign-encrypt-sign is it helping when the PKE scheme is not CCA-secure. $\:$ (A CCA attack would probably involve some invalid ciphertexts, and the outer signature would identify the responsible party.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: The idea behind sign-encrypt-sign is that encrypt-then-sign ($C=E(M)||S(E(M))$) would allow to take the encrypted message and claim ownership over it (by signing it with the key of the adversary), while sign-then-encrypt ($C=E(M||S(M))$) allows for *surreptitious forwarding* (the recipient decrypts the message and the signature and can send it two a third party on the sender's behalf). Here is a relevant link that describes better these scenarios http://world.std.com/~dtd/sign_encrypt/sign_encrypt7.html

Comment: @Sergio : $\:$ _If_ the PKE scheme is CCA-secure, then sign-then-encrypt _done properly_ will be optimal, since it will also hide the sender's identity from everyone other than the receiver. $\;\;\;\;$